# Is it possible to remove a html element using nightmarejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nightmare

I would like to know how to remove a html element based on its id when I load a website using nightmare js.

Thanks

Comment: Just guessing, can you use evaluatefn to remove it?
 https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You are capable of using the .evaluate() method so that you can then run vanilla JS code, in which you could use a JQuery command to accomplish what you need...

```
var test = new Nightmare()
  .goto("https://www.google.com")
  .evaluate(function() {
    $("#selectorID").remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = new Nightmare()
  .goto("https://www.google.com")
  .evaluate(function() {
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
  });
```